# Default arguments plus conditionals as polymorphism in Python, a good practice?

Tags: python, polymorphism

I am writing a program for fluid structure interaction in Python. I have found that I am creating several functions or methods with the same kind of "polymorphic pattern"; it works pretty well and I keep things simple, but I am not sure if it is a good practice. A simple case would be as follows.

Imagine we have two dictionaries for the material properties, one for the fluid and one for the solid. Suppose I need to convert the units in which the constants are measured; since the constants for the solid and for the fluid are different, I write the function as:

```
def convert(solid=None, fluid=None, constants=None, unit):
    # Unit conversion
    if unit == "mm":
        print("--> Converting constant units to mm.")
        if constants:
            constants["g"] *= 9800.0
        if fluid:
            print("--> Converting fluid units to mm.")
            fluid["rho"] *= 1.0E-9
            fluid["mu"] *= 1.0E-3
        if solid:
            print("--> Converting solid units to mm.")
            solid["G"] *= 1.0E-9
            solid["E"] *= 1.0E-3
```

I am not sure if it is a good approach, since I always try to avoid the use of conditionals; but in this case I keep the code simple without the necessity of writing a class and instantiating a conversion object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not polymorphism per se, really, but function overriding. C++ (among others) provides this mechanism by allowing multiple definition of functions with the same names, but with different number and types of arguments (i.e., function signatures). Python, being dynamically typed at its base, cannot provide this pattern. The question you should ask is if the idea of function overriding is a good one or not. I have seen it frowned upon occasionally, but it is very widely used.

The use of arguments with default values and conditional processing is just Python's way of providing a similar mechanism to C++'s function overriding.

My rule of thumb is that if most of the processing done by a function is common, then I use this pattern. However, if most of the processing depends on the functions signature (i.e., which variables get non-default values), I use different function names. In your case, something like:

- `convert_from_solid`
- `convert_from_fluid`
- `convert_from_constants`

I think, though, that this question is more about opinion.

Comment: Thank you much for your answer @Amitai Irron. Since I am not a programmer, it helps me a lot to understand this important concept. When this question appear in my mind, I often find C++ answers to be easier than Python.